# Snowflake bulk insert with select query in nodejs

Tags: binding, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert into table with select statement and setting bind variable. I get bind variable not set error. But the same works if it is just insert with bind variables. When I'm using with select it is giving this error.

```
connection.execute({
sqlText:  'insert into table1(col1, col2, col3) select distinct col1, ?,? from table2 where col2=?',
binds: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get bind variable not set error.

The third bind variable is not set:

```
sqlText:  '... select distinct col1, ?,? from table2 where col2=?'
                                     | |                        |
                                     1 2                        3
```

So there are three bind placeholders, but only two array members in the bind:

```
binds: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
        ---1--- ---2---
```

If you only need to pass two bind variables (two arrays), you can use the same bind variable more than once by referencing it like `:1` and `:2`

```
sqlText:  '... select distinct col1, :1,:2 from table2 where col2=:2'
```

The thing is, even if you supply a third bind variable I'm not sure it will work. Other external clients (JDBC, ODBC) cannot bind arrays. It may work in Node.js, but if not you can send the arrays as strings and use the `split` function on them in the SQL to split them into arrays.

Comment: Within array I'm passing 3 values. [1,2,3] which i am expecting to consider as 3 bind parameters. Like I said I'm trying to do bulk insert, which works fine without select statement in this format. Here I'm trying to achieve with select statement and I'm getting this error. The inner array is what is my bind parameters

Comment: `binds` takes an array. The number of array members needs to match the number of `?` placeholders or the highest numbered placeholder `:1`, `:2`, `:3`. In this case, you're sending arrays as each variable but the number of array members there does not matter for matching the bind variables. Only the top-level array member count matters.

Comment: But in official docs also it is mentioned something like this - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/nodejs-driver-use.html#binding-array-for-bulk-insert

Comment: That shows three array members in the top level array: `[[1, 'string1', 2.0], [2, 'string2', 4.0], [3, 'string3', 6.0]]` This is an array of arrays 3x3.